# Can Perl manage subroutines in dynamic structures?

Tags: perl

I have a set of parse funcitons. Some of them I need to apply, depending on the context.
Can I manage functions in arrays or something in Perl, e.g. like in JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Perl is a functional language just like Javascript. Basically, you replace `function` with `sub` and leave out the function prototype. Here is an example of three subs that print out something:

```
my @subs = (
  sub {print "Sub 1\n"},
  sub {my ($arg) = (@_, 2); print "Sub $arg\n"},
  \&my_function
);
sub my_function {
  print "Sub 3\n"
}

foreach my $function (@subs) {
  $function->("Argument");
}
```

prints

```
Sub 1
Sub Argument
Sub 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `sub {...}` in Perl is just like `function () {...}` in JavaScript.